# Fill the whole container of grouped shapes - Excel

Tags: excel

I have create some shapes in Excel, group them together and i can not find how to apply fill color on the whole group. Not on the shapes but on the background.

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In short, this isn't possible on a shape group.

**Detailed explanation:**

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.groupshapes

> The GroupedShapes object "Represents the individual shapes within a
>   grouped shape."

Because the group itself only represents the shapes within it, it doesn't have its own fill colour as such, only the fill colours of the shapes within it.

So, as I guess you've discovered, if you do something like this:

```
With Sheet1.Shapes(1).GroupItems.Parent
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
```

Then you are telling the group to apply the `Forecolor` to every shape within the group, and not the group object itself.

If you wish to have a background colour to the group, then a workaround would be to create a rectangle at the back, and set the colour of that instead.

**Update: Workaround Example**

If you wish to implement my suggested workaround, then the following will get you there. You will need to adjust for colours / workbook / worksheet / shape group name etc. There might be a prettier way, but I have this working...

```
Const shapeGroupName As String = "ShapeGroup"
Const shapeGroupBGName As String = "ShapeGroupBG"
Const shapeGroupMargin As Single = 5

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim w As Integer

Dim shapeCount As Integer
Dim shapeCol() As String

With Sheet1.shapes.Range(Array(shapeGroupName))
    ReDim Preserve shapeCol(.GroupItems.Count)
    For shapeCount = 1 To .GroupItems.Count
        shapeCol(shapeCount) = .GroupItems.Item(shapeCount).Name
    Next

    y = .Top - shapeGroupMargin
    x = .Left - shapeGroupMargin
    h = .Height + shapeGroupMargin * 2
    w = .Width + shapeGroupMargin * 2
    .Ungroup
End With

shapeCol(0) = shapeGroupBGName
With Sheet1.shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, x, y, w, h)
    .Name = shapeGroupBGName
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Line.DashStyle = msoLineDashDot
    .ZOrder msoSendToBack
End With

With Sheet1.shapes.Range(shapeCol).Group
    .Name = shapeGroupName
End With
```

This works by getting the dimensions of the group, and the names of the shapes within it. Next it ungroups the shapes, adds a rectangle behind the existing shapes, and then regroups accordingly.

A couple of notes:

I have created an arbitrary margin size, as the dimensions of the group are actually the top left and bottom right of the objects within it. In excel, the GUI adds a nice bit extra on to this, so its up to you to set this to what you want.

You can also implement a different shape (i.e. a rounded rectangle instead if desired etc.).

If you have multiple shape groups, then the above could be modified easily to accommodate this.

Comment: You're welcome. I think this poses a different question then to address the workaround: Are you wanting to know how to create a rectangle in a group, send it to the back of the other objects there?